# Are trust levels in ASP.NET 4.0 obsolete?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, code-access-security

Microsoft introduced a new security model on .NET 4.0 and above which is a replacement for *code access security*. **Since *trust levels* are *code access security***, is this approach obsolete?

If above statement is in the right way, how do you define a *PermissionSet* for a concrete ASP.NET application in .NET 4.x?

Comment: Voted to close before I read the whole thing..silly me.  The first part of your question belongs on programmers.se.  I'd recommend moving it and sticking with your second question here.

Comment: @ChrisLively Why belongs to programmers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ASP.NET trust levels are not obsolete.  Your concern that this might be the case seems to be due to a misunderstanding of how CAS has changed in .NET 4.0.  CAS has not actually been replaced.  Instead, there have been two major changes in how CAS is *enforced*:

1. The [transparency mechanism now plays a key role in code permission enforcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2009/11/09/transparency-as-enforcement-in-clr-v4.aspx) and
2. The "naked" [CLR no longer enforces CAS policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2010/02/24/so-is-cas-dead-in-net-4-or-what.aspx).

However, if you read the second linked article above, you will see that it is fully expected that hosts such as ASP.NET will continue to enforce CAS permission restrictions.  Unless you see a direct indication that some future version of ASP.NET will handle code permission restrictions differently, you should continue to rely on trust levels just as you have in the past.

Comment: +1 NicoleCalinoiu Thank you for your clarification and for these links, very useful for me and others.